# Изменение значений / обрезка читаемых значений

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток.

Есть такая задача:

При чтении значений с геймада, стик выдаёт значения:

```
Крайнее левое положение: -32768;
Центральное положение: 1792;
Крайнее правое положение: 32768;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в крайнем левом выдавал: 180, в центре: 90, крайнем правом - 0?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте что-типа этого:

```
def normalize(inp):        
    divisor = 32768 / 90
    if inp > 0:
        return 90 - (inp / divisor)
    if inp == 0:
        return 90
    inp = -inp
    return (inp / divisor) + 90


print(normalize(-32768))
print(normalize(0))
print(normalize(32768))
```

Comment: Так автору же нужно, чтобы в `90` превращалось не `0`, а `1792`.

Comment: Очевидный неверный результат для диапазона от 0 до 1792, а значит, и для всех остальных значений тоже.

Comment: @Yaant автор находиться в реальном мире с реальным контроллером. Мне думаеться что автор просто не смог держать руку на центре рукояти, чем что инженры контроллера вдруг стали считать 0 как 1792.

Comment: Кроме того не ясно, если 0 это 1792, то -1 это -1 или -1793?

Comment: Это же выглядит странно, но в любом случае навреняка сможет сказать лишь автор, после того как протетстит этот код...

Comment: @AndrioSkur Ну, вообще-то у контроллера стик возвращается в нейтральное положение при его отпускании. Держать не надо. И да, такой сдвиг  нейтрального значения - это как раз явление реального мира, которое и компенсируется необходимой автору калибровкой. :)

Comment: Дык калибровка это другая задача по отношению к конвертации в градусы. С таким количеством данных как в в опросе её не решить.

Comment: @AndrioSkur Да ну, почему не решить? Шкалу считаем линейной, сдвигаем середину в 0, соответственно сжимаем/растягиваем левый и правый диапазоны. Ну а потом уже можно и в градусы. :)

Comment: @Yaant ну во первых не понятно почему сжатие/расжатие а не сдвиг. Во 2 код должен быть стабильным, а у вас послезавтра износиться контроллер чуть больше и что переписовать код? Я уже даже не говорю про возможность подключения другого контроллера или переноса проги на другой комп.

Comment: @AndrioSkur Стесняюсь спросить, Вы когда-нибудь видели встроенную в Windows программу калибровки? Я практически уверен, что там для каждого контроллера используется одна и та же функция, которую никто не переписывает при подключении другого геймпада. :) А сжатие/расжатие, потому что оно все равно потребуется для нормализации результатов.